# NodeJS why is not restarting itself from code?

Tags: node.js, ssh

I need to restart app.js using SSH and try this code:

```
/* APP - restart */
conn = new client()

/* SSH - connection */
conn.on('ready', function() {
    /* SSH - restart */
    conn.exec('killall -2 node && node --expose-gc /root/myfolderaps/app.js', function(err, stream) {
        /* SSH - restart error */
        if (err) return callback('Restart <b>'+results[Object.keys(results)][2]+'</b> Failed!');

        /* SSH - close */
        conn.end();

        /* APP - restarted */
        res.json({'status': 'true', 'message': 'Restarting <b>'+results[Object.keys(results)][2]+'</b> Success!'});
    })
}).on('error', function(err) {
    /* SSH - connection failed */
    if(err) return callback('Login To <b>'+results[Object.keys(results)][2]+'</b> Failed!');
}).connect({
    host: results[Object.keys(results)][3],
    port: '22',
    username: 'root',
    password: decrypt(results[Object.keys(results)][5], password),
    readyTimeout: 3000
})
```

I'm using this library in node to connect to SSH and execute:

```
https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2
```

The problem is that it connects successfully to server using SSH, execute command and kill node master and child process and is NOT starting my app master process (in master process i have code that start child process for clustering).

So logically i don't know why this does not work i added && and with this means when first command is success do another command so this commands do the following:

```
killall -2 node && node --expose-gc /root/myfolderaps/app.js
```

Kill node master process
Start node app.js master process

But it only kills it not starting. How should I rewrite the code?

Comment: If you're killing the master process which controls the child processes, why would you expect the child processes to auto restart? Is there some missing information here, such as you're using nodemon/pm2/systemd/upstart/monit/etc. to automatically restart your master process when it dies?

Comment: Also, are you sure the master process is dying? Signal 2 is SIGINT. Are you explicitly handling this signal in your master process?

Comment: Lastly, why kill the master AND the child processes? Why not just signal in one form or another the master process to restart its child processes, instead of killing them directly (which may be viewed as an unexpected event rather than the master doing it which would be viewed as a normal/expected child process exit)?

Comment: I have apps.js that is doing heavy work..and for some reason apps.js lock all cpu cores to 100% or RAM usage goes close to 100% usage...i want to restart whole apps.js not only child process...if in this case i restart only child process will apps.js release CPU and RAM usage or will be the same? i im asking because i think i need to kill master process and then start master process again (because master process controls child process so if i kill master process i kill child process and then start master process witch starts child process)...if i im wrong please let me know